# Git Large File Storage not pushing to repo despite successful uploading of LFS objects

Tags: git, github, push, git-push, git-lfs

When I run `git lfs ls-files -s`, LFS tells me that the files are getting tracked:

```
72face5c11 - client/data.ms/indexes/18a4b1f0-393d-434d-9129-9f15c834fb61/data.mdb (335 MB)
1c383961b7 - client/meilisearch (240 MB)
```

However when I do `git push origin master`, I run into the following error:

```
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (2/2), 576 MB | 0 B/s, done.                                             
Enumerating objects: 243, done.
Counting objects: 100% (243/243), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (229/229), done.
Writing objects: 100% (239/239), 197.80 MiB | 1.05 MiB/s, done.
Total 239 (delta 111), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (111/111), completed with 2 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 173bb3fae212a36eacc3d98786ab6b65b65ca04ec69e58ab805404ea536c7cbc
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File meilisearch is 229.14 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File data.ms/indexes/18a4b1f0-393d-434d-9129-9f15c834fb61/data.mdb is 319.81 MB; this 
exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB                                                        remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-
lfs.github.com.                                                                                      To github.com:Gaurav-Narayan-Varma/healthmaps.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'my-git-repo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the error messages carefully. The Git LFS message and the error from the GitHub pre-receive hook are about two different files. The former is under `client/data.ms`, the latter under `data.ms`.

Just remove the files/directories GitHub is complaining about and do `git commit --amend`.

Also make sure to remove the files not only in the most recent commit but also in the ancestor commits using `git rebase - i` if necessary.